# Return a razor view into an Iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I create a small form and give the link to my customer so he include the view in one `IFRAME` in his page and show ok.

When user submit the `IFRAME` form instead of redraw inside the `IFRAME` take the whole page.

```
...
ViewBag.result = "Form send correctly";
return View();
```

What should I use instead  `return View();` ?

Comment: What if you set the form's `target` attribute to `_self`?  (This *should* be the default, but it's worth trying explicitly.)  This isn't really anything you can control from server-side code.  It's up to the client-side code and the browser to determine what to do in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is not on the controller. It is on your `View`. You could try set a name for the elements `iframe` and target your form to post on this element, for sample:

```
<iframe src="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")" name="foo"></iframe>
```

and in your View inside the iFrame

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { target = "foo" })
{
  ..
}
```

Comment: The Iframe isnt on my View right now. So should I add a virtural Iframe and refresh there?

Comment: Yes, it is not, can you add an `attribute` `name` for it? If not, you need to do a javascript code to get the reference of this element and set it on the target of your form, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: Yes, I can have the `IFrame ID`, but that page is PHP, So they only use `src=myLink`. What javascript function should I look for?

Comment: So no need javascriprt? only `new { target = "foo" }` ?

Comment: If you can set a name for the iframe just use it on your form on the view inside the iframe. In this case, you do not need a javascript. And make sure you set the name of iframe, it is not the id.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is, It shows the layout which you do not want to be shown in the iFrame.

You can disable the layout in the razor view

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

If you remove the layout from the page, you will loose all the JS and CSS you loaded via the Layout file. In that case, you may use a minimalistic Layout which still has reference to your required CSS/JS files.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MyMiniLayout.cshtml;
}
```

You can customize the `MyMiniLayout` the way you want.

You may show another view once the form submit is completed instead of showing the same view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(string name)
{
  // to do :Do something with posted data
  return RedirectToAction("FormSubmitted");
}
public ActionResult FormSubmitted()
{ 
  return View();
}
```

You can put whatever markup you want to show to user in the `FormSubmitted` view.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<h2>Submitted successfully</h2>
```

Comment: No, the problem is customer page is php, he just put my link there and show ok. But when click my link show full page, not inside iframe

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza You can customize what you want to show. Just show another view as needed. See my updated answer.